# Sorting items by their Color

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a basket of flowers and I want them to tag and sort by their Color. Any ideas on how this can be done, will be very helpful.

Thanks much for your time.

Comment: I love this question. rofling . Please provide more details.

Comment: @normalone: How are you currently representing the contents of your basket? What do you mean by "tag"? "sort"? Do you really mean "group" instead of "sort"? If not, how do you order colours, which are usually specified by a 3-tuple of numbers e.g. (red, green, blue)? Is red > blue, or is red < blue?

Comment: @John Machin If you have the rgb/hex values it's actually very easy to sort colours from one end of the spectrum to the other.

Comment: I believe the order of colors goes something like this: ROYGBIV

Comment: @Endophage, @Scott M.: You are talking about colours which have a single wavelength. The RGB colours that are used in CSS etc contain many that are a mixture of multiple wavelengths.

Comment: @John Machin They do indeed.  However the spectrum of colours goes from the red end to the blue end so by designing a wave function you can create a colour generator that goes from reds, through greens, to blues.  It's something I've actually done for theming pagination links on a web page.  Using a similar system you can apply an ordering to colours.

Comment: @Endophage: Your ordering is one of many arbitrary orderings obtained by `key=f(r,g,b)` or `key=g(h,s,v)`

Comment: @John Machin I wouldn't call an ordering based on the electromagnetic spectrum wavelengths arbitrary.  The RGB colour space is merely a set of finite points through the spectrum.

Comment: Everyone sorts colors in the HSV or HSL color spaces. Don't sort RGB colors (and definitely don't do it by *name*); convert them first, and then sort primarily by Hue, secondarily by value/lightness. The diagram in Blindy's answer should give you the right idea. I'd post a C# example, but I doubt it'd be of much help if you want to do this in PHP or Python.

Comment: Yea, I initially posted a 2 liner in C#, but I wasn't sure if it would be of any help to him since he hasn't mentioned a language.

Answer (score 9):

The most obvious solution would seem to order by hue.

This would give you a stable sorting comparison operator that would sort your array in this order:
[image]

Note that some RGB colors are degenerate in the sense that they don't have a single HLS form. White is such an example. It's up to you how you're going to handle them.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question (despite being blind?)

Comment: Add also a vertical scale for "saturation," if two colors are hue-ly the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the concept of **[Lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)**.

Basically, given the HSL representations of 2 colors (say `C1 = (H1, S1, L1)` and `C2 = (H2, S2, L2)`), we can define `C1 < C2` if and only if `((H1 < H2) || (H1 == H2 && S1 < S2) || (H1 == H2 && S1 == S2 && L1 < L2))`, and `C1 == C2` if and only if `H1 == H2 && S1 == S2 && L1 == L2`. Similarly for `C1>C2`.

This will order the colors first by hue; then by saturation to resolve hue conflicts; and finally by lightness to resolve hue and saturation conflicts.

I've used the precedence order `H > S > L` in this example, but you could just as easily use some other order according to your needs, or maybe even another color respresentation (e.g., RGB).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort it by the actual color, not alphabetically by the name of the color, then the solution isn't very obvious.  Sorting is normally done on entities where a clear "greater than" and "less than" semantic can be defined.  Colors, though, don't have such a semantic because they're represented by 3 numbers generally (either RGB or HSV).  You would have to arbitrarily define your own "ordering" and then sort using that.

Comment: This is true to some extent. But I'm willing to bet that you have some intuitive feel as to what a set of "unordered" colors vs. a set of "ordered" colors looks like. The issue is how to capture that in code.

Comment: My first thought was ordering by hue, like Blindy's answer. But then when I followed that thought through I ran into all sorts of problems.  What about colors that are highly desaturated? How would you sort <255,0,0> and <100,0,0>? You could sort on hue, then saturation, then value. Or red, then green, then blue.  That's what I was getting at in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare colors in java see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/UsingthegetRGBmethodforcomparingcolors.htm)

Comment: This is comparing for equality, not for larger/less.

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking the principal components of variance, then projecting on that axis. (So if all the colours are shades of red, red is non-zero, green and blue are both zero, and the algorithm would say the axis is 1.0, 0.0, 0.0. It then sorts on red. If they are all shades of yellow, then that axis is root(0.5), root(0.5), 0.0, it averages the red and green, and sorts on that).
It won't work well if the colours form three or more distinct "clouds".